# Ruby Recursive replace in arrays

Tags: ruby, recursion

I have an object, `tree`. `tree` has a property, `tree.elements`. `tree.elements`is an array containing both elements and possibly other sub-trees, which in turn will have their own `elements` array, and so on.

I need a method which will be able to replace objects in the tree if they are of a certain class. The problem is replacing elements inline.

Obviously, the following will not work:

```
[1,2,3].each { |n| n = 1 }
# => [1,2,3]
```

But, this will:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.each_with_index { |n, idx| a[idx] = 1 }
# => [1,1,1]
```

However, I am using a recursive function to loop through, and replacing placeholders with content, like so:

```
def replace_placeholders(elements)
    elements.each do |e|
        if e.respond_to?(:elements) and e.elements.any?
            replace_placeholders(e.elements)
        elsif e.is_a? Placeholder
            e = "some new content" # << replace it here
        end
    end
end
```

Keeping track of the indices is really complicated. I've tried `e.replace("some new content")`, but that doesn't work.  What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Is replacing elements inline super-essential? Without it, it becomes much easier.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev no, it's not - don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a new array rather than trying to update in-place. Something along these lines should work:

```
def replace_placeholders(elements)
  elements.map do |e|
    if e.respond_to?(:elements) and e.elements.any?
      e.elements = replace_placeholders(e.elements) # replace array
      e  # return e itself, so that map works correctly.
    elsif e.is_a? Placeholder
      "some new content"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, works great - one thing I needed to do though was to add an else statement and return e there, as otherwise I would be dropping elements, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Array#collect:

```
[1,2,3].collect { |n| 1 }
# => [1,1,1]
```

And do whatever you want with this block parameter.

So your code will go something like this:

```
elements.collect{ |n| if n.respond_to?(:elements) and n.elements.any?
        replace_placeholders(n.elements)
    elsif n.is_a? Placeholder
        "some new content" # << replace it here
    end
}
```